# Criterion for triviality of projective bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety and $\pi:W \to X$ be a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle of $X$. Suppose that there exists a section of $\pi$ in the sense that there exists a morphism $s:X \to W$ such that $\pi \circ s$ is identity on $X$. Does this imply that $W$ is a trivial $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $X$? If not true in general, is it true if $X$ is a smooth rational curve?

Comment: Sorry, I probably misinterpreted your question. I read ``trivial $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle" as any projective-bundle which is the projectivization of a vector bundle. If you have a section $s:X\rightarrow W$ then this implies that $W$ is the (relative proj) of a locally free sheaf on $X$. If you were asking whether or not $W=X\times \mathbb{P}^1$ then this isn't true. If $X$ is a curve then just having $\mathbb{P}^1$ as fibers of the map $\pi$ implies the existence of a section. But there are nonisomorphic projective bundles over $X$. See Hartshorne Chapter 5 Section 2 for more details.

Comment: @Eoin Why is the existence of $\mathbb{P}^1$ as fibers implies the existence of a section?

Comment: Harteshorne cites ``Algebraic Surfaces" by Shafarevich, Proc. Steklov. Inst. Math. 75 (1965) (trans by A.M.S. 1967), page 24.

Answer (score 1):

No.

It's almost like you are asking for the case of [Hirzebruch surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch_surface). By construction, write 
$$H_n = \mathbb{P} (O \oplus O(n)),$$ 
where $O, O(n)$ are line bundles on $\mathbb P^1$. $H_n$ obviously has a structure of a $\mathbb P^1$ bundle over $\mathbb P^1$ and it has a section given by $O$.

However, almost all of them are not trivial bundles.

Comment: I understand a zero section of a vector bundle. What is a zero section of a projective bundle as it is constructed after removing the zero section?

Comment: Yes, that's a wrong term. There is always a line $O(0)\times \{0\}$ in $O(0) \oplus O(n)$. So there is always a section (yes this shouldn't be called a zero section). @Ron

Comment: But on the other hand, if you think of $\mathbb{P} (\mathbb C \oplus L)$ as adding a point to $L$, then the zero section in $\mathbb{P} (\mathbb C \oplus L)$ is really the zero at $0\in L$. So the term "zero section" might still be okay. @Ron

Comment: However, if there are two sections that do not intersect, then the bundle is trivial.